# Difficulties with jQuery's fadeIn() & hide()

Tags: jquery, jqueryform

I'm guessing I am misunderstanding how to accomplish a fadeIn() of an element which I am adding via jquery.form.js, but after trying things I've found on other posts I have gotten nowhere.  I'm still learning jQuery and javascript so maybe my error is something simple there.

I have the following line of code in the success of my jquery.form.js ajaxForm

```
jQuery('#aThankYouTarget').append(jQuery("<p>"+data+"</p>")).fadeIn(1000);
```

I have tried variations on this line and cannot seem to see fading results.  My data is coming up exactly as expected, it just lacks the fade.  I have also tried putting a hide() in like follows, but when I do that the hide seems to work but the fadeIn never happens there either.

```
jQuery('#aThankYouTarget').append(jQuery("<p>"+data+"</p>").hide()).fadeIn(1000);
```

Also as suggested on another question here I have tried with data as follows.  I think it was "text" that I used anyway, as I have long since forgotten what that person suggested when it wasn't working either.

```
jQuery('#aThankYouTarget').append(jQuery("<p></p>").text(data.content).hide()).fadeIn(1000);
```

I'd really prefer something similar to my first example as it keeps the paragraph section of the javascript looking the most like the html will in the end and I feel it is easier to read, but if someone wants to talk me into creating the element, and adding text to it I could probably be persuaded.  The main thing is that I find out how to get the fadeIn() working.

Thank you.

Edit: #aThankYouTarget is a div, with paragraphs inside of it.  When the page is loaded some paragraphs are possibly already there.  The fadeIn I wish to do is for any newly added paragraphs after the form submission to fade in.

Comment: As a word of safety, I would recommend doing `$('<p>').text(data)` to restrict any possibilities of `data` being malformed and inserting something you don't want. Either are acceptable however and really just person opinion.

Comment: @Brad Christie, I knew that was coming :), which is why I mentioned I could be persuaded :).  I'm going to sleep on it.  I can't decide which way I like better.  Thanks for making me think about it, I'm sure it's a good thing.

Comment: Was merely a nudge. It comes down to if you feel comfortable or not. ;-)

Comment: @Brad Christie, yep.  I might have to write them both out on a piece of paper and stare at them while I'm eating breakfast :D.  I do appreciate your suggestion, just not sure yet if I'm going to go that route or not.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were awfully close. You do need to `.hide()` first, but you were *fading* the wrong thing!

```
jQuery("<p>"+data+"</p>").appendTo('#aThankYouTarget').hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

Note: switched the order around so that the `<p>` becomes the main object. `.hide()` and `.fadeIn()` will now both operate on the `<p>`, *after* it has been appended.

Comment: Yes.  My intent is to have the <p>foo</p> be the part that fades in.  An example would be this very comment box I'm typing in right now.  I want the "comment" I just typed to fade in, but previous stuff should stay solid.  So I believe I was totally intending to do the fadin on the <p> but was getting nothing.

Comment: @wilbbe01, wasn't sure from your question. In that case, you were *fading* the wrong thing. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well that is totally awesome.  I do remember looking at the jquery api and reading about appendTo vs append.  Maybe had I done appendto in the first place it would have made more sense.  After looking at it now this works too.  jQuery('#aThankYouTarget').append(jQuery("<p>"+data+"</p>").hide().fadeIn(1000));  I was looking at it too functionlike I think.  I was reading left to right and stopping at dots....and seeing it as "why on earth would I want to fade in before it is appended?")  That caused me to put the fadeIn at the end.  Thanks much for your assistance.